# "Otomatone", is it made by combining "sound" and "hand"?

Tags: translation, puns

"Otomatone", is it made by combining "sound" and "hand"?

Wiktionary confirms that "oto" is ["sound"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sound#Translations_2), but not that "mato" means ["hand"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hand/translations#Noun).

Sources: [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Otamatone+%22hand+sound%22&hl=en) [1](https://everythingotamatone.com/blogs/news/otamatone-the-strange-japanese-instrument), [2](https://oleosymusica.blog/en/what-sound-does-an-otamatone-make/), [3](https://www.musicianauthority.com/otamatone/)

> What does Otamatone mean in Japanese?

> Its body is shaped like an eighth note (quaver) where the sound emerges from its mouth on the notehead. This two-handed synthesizer instrument’s name Otamatone is a combination of two words – “oto” which means sound and “mato” which means “hand sound”.

While Wikipedia [implies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otamatone#Description) that the name's based on "otamajakushi":

> The Otamatone is a synthesizer whose body is shaped like an eighth note (quaver) (it also somewhat resembles a tadpole, or a ladle, otamajakushi (お玉杓子 / おたまじゃくし) being Japanese for tadpole and ladle)

The translation of which is backed up by Wiktionary, of course, and [Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%8A%E7%8E%89%E6%9D%93%E5%AD%90).

Comment: 的 means 'target' and is the only word with 'mato' on its own I can think of. The closest body part is 股, the crotch.

Comment: And, for what it's worth, 股 with the meaning of "crotch" is pronounced _mata_. So that's not a match here either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your sources are probably wrong. Firstly, it is not ot**o**matone but ot**a**matone. As [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otamatone), オタマトーン{otamatōn} is made by combining オタマジャクシ{otamajakushi} (tadpole) and トーン{tōn} (tone). I've never heard of "mato" meaning "hand", and I'm Japanese.